# what is the idiomatic way to write this clojure snippet to concat collection with a string?

Tags: clojure, concatenation, idioms

Its best to explain what I am trying using an example.

Given a collection ["apple" "orange" "banana"] and concatenation string ","   function should produce  "apple,orange,banana"

Is this the idiomatic way to write this function?

```
user=> (defn my-concat[x st]
   (str (first x) (apply str (map #(str st %) (rest x)))))

user=> (my-concat "abcd" "!")
"a!b!c!d"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`interpose`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/interpose) function if you want a sequence, or [`clojure.string/join`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.string/join) if you just want the string result.

Comment: I looked at the clojure.string/join source. It is using StringBuilder. and loop/recur. I am wondering why did the authors choose that implementation? Could that be due to performance reasons?  join could be written as (apply str (interpose st coll)).

Comment: I timed both functions. clojure.string/join is always about 50% faster

Comment: Interpose does a lot more work to maintain the lazy interleaving of your collection and your separator. Join is optimized for a single resulting string.